# Span in $\mathbb{R}^3 $ for three column vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

A textbook question asks, for what values of h will y be in Span ${v_1, v_2, v_3}$ if

$v_1=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}$ and $v_2=\begin{bmatrix}5\\-4\\-7\end{bmatrix}$  and 
$v_3=\begin{bmatrix}-3\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$  and

$y=\begin{bmatrix}-4\\3\\h\end{bmatrix}$.

The answer is $5$ because the augmented matrix of the vectors above reduce to 
\begin{bmatrix}1&5&-3&4\\0&1&-2&-1\\0&0&0&h-5\end{bmatrix}

Thus, $h$ must equal $5$ to be consistent.

i. Conceptually, does this mean that $v_3$ was linearly dependent on the other two vectors, since otherwise the Span of $\mathbb{R}^3$ should be all real numbers in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

ii. Based on Khan's video on span, if they are linearly dependent this should mean that there are non-zero scalar values of $c_1, c_2, c_3$ such that

$c_1*\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\2\end{bmatrix}$ + $c_2*\begin{bmatrix}5\\-4\\-7\end{bmatrix}$  + 
$c_3*\begin{bmatrix}-3\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$  =
 $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Is this a correct understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding seems to be correct for the most part, let me just nitpick a bit on i:

If you write "$v_3$ is linearly dependent on $v_1, v_2$" you imply the existence of an equation $$v_3 = c_1 \cdot v_1 + c_2 \cdot v_2.$$
This is true in your case (as can be seen from the matrix form) but does not directly follow from the fact that the three vectors don't span the whole of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

The existence of $c_1,c_2,c_3$ such that $$c_1 \cdot v_1 + c_2 \cdot v_2 + c_3 \cdot v_3 = 0$$
(as you correctly wrote) is the right thing in general; one says "v_1, v_2, v_3 are linearly dependent". For an example, you could look at $v_1 = v_2 = (1,0,0)$ and $v_3 = (0,1,0)$, or at a family where one of them is the zero vector.